# Cassandra fatal exception InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: cassandra

I am running 0.8 cassandra. When I used CQL to create two secondary indexes on two different fields on the same table, I got one exception:

> javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

The worst thing about this exception is that if I shutdown the cassandra service, I can't start it anymore.

It keeps showing this exception as a fatal exception and prevent cassandra to start.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bug. Please report steps to reproduce and the full stacktrace of the exception on the issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Edit: as a workaround, you can connect to Cassandra with the cli after startup and drop either of the indexes, then restart the server and re-create the index with a different name.

Comment: Thanks! My real question is if this exception happened, how could I bypass it when starting cassandra service?

Comment: Guessing from the limited description, you'd probably have to blow away your system/ schema and migrations sstables, then recreate your schema. Best to report the bug and let us fix it. :)

Comment: ok, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2730 has been generated with the description how to replicate this bug.